# RegEx Exepression not matching

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text

```
CHAPTER 1
Introduction
CHAPTER OVERVIEW
```

Which I did create and tested (http://regexr.com/) the following regEx for

```
(CHAPTER\s{1}\d\n)
```

However when I use the following code on Java it fails

```
String text = stripper.getText(document);//The text above
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(CHAPTER\\s{1}\\d\\n)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        //do action
    }
```

the m.find() returns always false.

Comment: Might be a problem with matching a newline, could you try \r\n instead of just \n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document may have DOS line feed `\r` as well. You can use either of these patterns:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("CHAPTER\\s+\\d+\\R");
```

`\R` (requires Java 8) will match any combination of `\r` and `\n` after your digits or just use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("CHAPTER\\s+\\d+\\s");
```

since `\s` also matches any whitespace including newline characters.

**Another alternative** is to use `MULTILINE` flag with anchor `$`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)CHAPTER\\s+\\d+$");
```

Comment: Since Java 8, a better alternative to match line termination characters is [the meta-character `\R`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending). It will match `\r\n` (Windows), a single `\r` (old MacOSs), a single `\n` (Linux) and some other Unicode characters with the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks so much @Aaron, `\R` is definitely better (edited)

Comment: Unless you want to match empty lines, I think you can drop the `+` quantifier, since `\R` will match the whole `\r\n` sequence.

Comment: Thanks so much @anubhava for your help, tested and working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your source text. I think you forget about new lines. Because this:

```
String text = "CHAPTER 1\n" +
                "Introduction\n" +
                "CHAPTER OVERVIEW";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(CHAPTER\\s{1}\\d\\n)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        System.out.println(m.find());
```

will write **true**. String body is copied from here and Intellij add there new lines. Try to debug what you really get in `stripper.getText(document)`.
You can use Pattern as second param for compile. (Pattern.MULTILINE) More info

[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

.